# JavaScript: Simplify formula to avoid if statements

Tags: javascript, math

I think there is a way to write this code in a nicer way with single line formula that does not use `if` statements so that X (0 -> 0.5 -> 1) Y shoulde be (0 -> 1 -> 0).

```js
var h = 200;
var w = 200;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


for(var i = 0; i < w; i++){
   var x = i/w;
   var y;
   
   if(x < 0.5){
    y = 1 - x * 2;
   } else {
    y = (x - 0.5) * 2;
   }
   
   drawPoint(x, y);
}

function drawPoint(x, y){
  ctx.fillRect(x * w, y * h, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #aaa;"></canvas>
```

Comment: `1 - x * 2 === -(x - 0.5) * 2` (don't know why you put one into brackets and not the other). You have a condition, so you need an "if", or something similar. If you really don't want the if, you can always use e.g. `y = (1 - x * 2) * (x < 0.5 ? 1 : -1);`, but it is imho less readable.

Comment: single line formulas  = unnecessary  complexity

Comment: Ha! nonbelievers! @Dacre Denny done it! ^^

Comment: `I would however tend to avoid this numerical approach as, at a glance, it's not particularly clear what's going on` << This is every reason why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: how about `y = (x * 2 - 1) * Math.sign(x - 0.5)`

Comment: @georg yup this is it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). This would allow you to simplify the conditional logic to a single line as shown below:

```
const h = 200;
const w = 200;
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

for(var i = 0; i < w; i++){
   const x = i/w;

   // Use ternary operator, and apply factor to ternary result
   const y = ((x < 0.5) ? (1 - x) : (x - 0.5)) * 2;

   drawPoint(x, y);
}

function drawPoint(x, y){
  ctx.fillRect(x * w, y * h, 1, 1);
}
```

Note that this is technically still an "if-like" statement under the hood - it does however allow you to express equivlant logic to your original code in a single line.

If you *really* wanted to avoid an "if-like" statement, you could use the following numerical interpolation method to achieve what you require:

```
for(var i = 0; i < w; i++){
   const x = i/w;

   const c = Math.round(x); // Returns 0 if x < 0.5 otherwise 1
   const y = (((1 - c) * (1 - x)) + (c * (x - 0.5))) * 2;

   drawPoint(x, y);
}
```

I would tend to avoid this approach however as, at a glance, it's not particularly clear what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, but yes it's still if :(

Comment: @wyy my understanding if that you were wanting to avoid an explicity if, and reduce the original logic to a single like? "with single line formula and without if statements."